# Unity is unable to merge Android manifests build error

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

In my Unity project, I have imported the plugins: [Android Native Plugin](https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/10825) and Chartboost.

Before importing the Chartboost unity package, I can successfully build and run on my Android device. But after importing the Chartboost package, I get this error when I'm trying to build and run.

Here's the build error:

```
Error building Player: CommandInvokationFailure: Unable to merge android manifests. See the Console for more details. 
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_40.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java -Xmx2048M -Dcom.android.sdkmanager.toolsdir="/Users/user/Library/Android/sdk/tools" -Dfile.encoding=UTF8 -jar "/Applications/Unity/Unity.app/Contents/BuildTargetTools/AndroidPlayer/sdktools.jar" -

stderr[
Error: [Temp/StagingArea/AndroidManifest-main.xml:8, /Users/user/Documents/Unity Projects/Unity 5.0.0 projects/mygame/Temp/StagingArea/android-libraries/ChartboostSDK/AndroidManifest.xml:11] Trying to merge incompatible /manifest/application/meta-data[@name=com.google.android.gms.version] element:
  <meta-data
      @android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
--    @android:value="6587000">
  <meta-data
      @android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
++    @android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version">
Error: [Temp/StagingArea/AndroidManifest-main.xml:8, /Users/user/Documents/Unity Projects/Unity 5.0.0 projects/mygame/Temp/StagingArea/android-libraries/google-play-services_lib/AndroidManifest.xml:5] Trying to merge incompatible /manifest/application/meta-data[@name=com.google.android.gms.version] element:
  <meta-data
      @android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
--    @android:value="6587000">
  <meta-data
      @android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
++    @android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version">
]
stdout[

]
```

Still new to Android development so I'm kinda at a lost. I've seen some posts online regarding a similar issue and from what I understand is that whenever using multiple plugins, there would also be multiple manifest files and Unity sometimes fails to combine the manifests due to different/conflicting values.

I don't see any values conflicting in the error message though. How do I fix this? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Update: With the help of Max Yankov, I am able to get past the `Unable to merge manifests error`. But I am now presented with a new error `Unable to convert classes into dex format`

Here's the log for that error:

```
Error building Player: CommandInvokationFailure: Unable to convert classes into dex format. See the Console for details.
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_40.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java -Xmx2048M -Dcom.android.sdkmanager.toolsdir="/Users/user/Library/Android/sdk/tools" -Dfile.encoding=UTF8 -jar "/Applications/Unity/Unity.app/Contents/BuildTargetTools/AndroidPlayer/sdktools.jar" -

stderr[

UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added: Lcom/google/android/gms/actions/SearchIntents;
    at com.android.dx.dex.file.ClassDefsSection.add(ClassDefsSection.java:122)
    at com.android.dx.dex.file.DexFile.add(DexFile.java:161)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processClass(Main.java:732)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processFileBytes(Main.java:673)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.access$300(Main.java:83)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main$1.processFileBytes(Main.java:602)
    at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processArchive(ClassPathOpener.java:284)
    at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processOne(ClassPathOpener.java:166)
    at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processDirectory(ClassPathOpener.java:229)
    at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processOne(ClassPathOpener.java:158)
    at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.process(ClassPathOpener.java:144)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processOne(Main.java:632)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processAllFiles(Main.java:510)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:280)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:246)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:215)
    at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:106)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at SDKMain.main(SDKMain.java:129)
1 error; aborting
]

stdout[
processing archive bin/classes.jar...
processing com/unity3d/player/a$1.class...
processing com/unity3d/player/a$2.class...
processing com/unity3d/player/a$a.class...
processing com/unity3d/player/a.class...
processing com/unity3d/player/b$1.class...
processing com/unity3d/player/b$2.class...
processing com/unity3d/player/b.class...
processing com/unity3d/player/c.class...
processing com/unity3d/player/d$1.class...
processing com/unity3d/player/d$2.class...
processing com/unity3d/player/d.class...
processing com/unity3d/player/e.class...
processing com/unity3d/player/f.class...
processing com/unity3d/player/g.class...
processing com/unity3d/player/h.class...
processing com/unity3d/player/i.class...
processing com/unity3d/player/j$1.class...
processing com/unity3d/player/j$2$1$1.class...
processing com/unity3d/player/j$2$1.class...
processing com/unity3d/player/j$2.class...
processing com/unity3d/player/j.class...
processing com/unity3d/player/k$1.class...
processing com/unity3d/player/k.class...
processing com/unity3d/player/l.class...
processing com/unity3d/player/m.class...
processing com/unity3d/player/n$1.class...
processing com/unity3d/player/n.class...
processing com/unity3d/player/NativeLoader.class...
processing com/unity3d/player/o.class...
processing com/unity3d/player/ReflectionHelper$1.class...
processing com/unity3d/player/ReflectionHelper$a.class...
processing com/unity3d/player/ReflectionHelper.class...
processing com/unity3d/player/p.class...
processing com/unity3d/player/q$1.class...
processing com/unity3d/player/q$2.class...
processing com/unity3d/player/q$3.class...
processing com/unity3d/player/q.class...
processing com/unity3d/player/r.class...
processing com/unity3d/player/s.class...
processing com/unity3d/player/UnityPlayer$1.class...
processing com/unity3d/player/UnityPlayer$2.class...
processing com/unity3d/player/UnityPlayer$3.class...
processing com/unity3d/player/UnityPlayer$4.class...
processing com/unity3d/player/UnityPlayer$5.class...
processing com/unity3d/player/UnityPlayer$6.class...
processing com/unity3d/player/UnityPlayer$7.class...
processing com/unity3d/player/UnityPlayer$8.class...
processing com/unity3d/player/UnityPlayer$9.class...
processing com/unity3d/player/UnityPlayer$10.class...
processing com/unity3d/player/UnityPlayer$11.class...
processing com/unity3d/player/UnityPlayer$12$1.class...
processing com/unity3d/player/UnityPlayer$12.class...
processing com/unity3d/player/UnityPlayer$13.class...
processing com/unity3d/player/UnityPlayer$14.class...
processing com/unity3d/player/UnityPlayer$15.class...
processing com/unity3d/player/UnityPlayer$16.class...
processing com/unity3d/player/UnityPlayer$17.class...
processing com/unity3d/player/UnityPlayer$18.class...
processing com/unity3d/player/UnityPlayer$a.class...
processing com/unity3d/player/UnityPlayer$b.class...
processing com/unity3d/player/UnityPlayer$c.class...
processing com/unity3d/player/UnityPlayer.class...
processing com/unity3d/player/UnityPlayerActivity.class...
processing com/unity3d/player/UnityPlayerNativeActivity.class...
processing com/unity3d/player/UnityPlayerProxyActivity.class...
processing com/unity3d/player/t.class...
processing com/unity3d/player/u$1.class...
processing com/unity3d/player/u.class...
processing com/unity3d/player/WWW.class...
processing org/fmod/FMODAudioDevice$a.class...
processing org/fmod/FMODAudioDevice.class...
processing org/fmod/a.class...
processing bin/classes/./com/chartboost/sdk/unity/Manifest$permission.class...
processing bin/classes/./com/chartboost/sdk/unity/Manifest.class...
processing bin/classes/./com/chartboost/sdk/unity/R$attr.class...
processing bin/classes/./com/chartboost/sdk/unity/R$bool.class...
processing bin/classes/./com/chartboost/sdk/unity/R$color.class...
processing bin/classes/./com/chartboost/sdk/unity/R$dimen.class...
processing bin/classes/./com/chartboost/sdk/unity/R$drawable.class...
processing bin/classes/./com/chartboost/sdk/unity/R$id.class...
processing bin/classes/./com/chartboost/sdk/unity/R$integer.class...
processing bin/classes/./com/chartboost/sdk/unity/R$layout.class...
processing bin/classes/./com/chartboost/sdk/unity/R$raw.class...
processing bin/classes/./com/chartboost/sdk/unity/R$string.class...
processing bin/classes/./com/chartboost/sdk/unity/R$style.class...
processing bin/classes/./com/chartboost/sdk/unity/R$styleable.class...
processing bin/classes/./com/chartboost/sdk/unity/R$xml.class...
processing bin/classes/./com/chartboost/sdk/unity/R.class...
processing bin/classes/./com/facebook/android/Manifest$permission.class...
processing bin/classes/./com/facebook/android/Manifest.class...
processing bin/classes/./com/facebook/android/R$attr.class...
processing bin/classes/./com/facebook/android/R$bool.class...
processing bin/classes/./com/facebook/android/R$color.class...
processing bin/classes/./com/facebook/android/R$dimen.class...
processing bin/classes/./com/facebook/android/R$drawable.class...
processing bin/classes/./com/facebook/android/R$id.class...
processing bin/classes/./com/facebook/android/R$integer.class...
processing bin/classes/./com/facebook/android/R$layout.class...
processing bin/classes/./com/facebook/android/R$raw.class...
processing bin/classes/./com/facebook/android/R$string.class...
processing bin/classes/./com/facebook/android/R$style.class...
processing bin/classes/./com/facebook/android/R$styleable.class...
processing bin/classes/./com/facebook/android/R$xml.class...
processing bin/classes/./com/facebook/android/R.class...
processing bin/classes/./com/google/android/gms/Manifest$permission.class...
processing bin/classes/./com/google/android/gms/Manifest.class...
processing bin/classes/./com/google/android/gms/R$attr.class...
processing bin/classes/./com/google/android/gms/R$bool.class...
processing bin/classes/./com/google/android/gms/R$color.class...
processing bin/classes/./com/google/android/gms/R$dimen.class...
processing bin/classes/./com/google/android/gms/R$drawable.class...
processing bin/classes/./com/google/android/gms/R$id.class...
processing bin/classes/./com/google/android/gms/R$integer.class...
processing bin/classes/./com/google/android/gms/R$layout.class...
processing bin/classes/./com/google/android/gms/R$raw.class...
processing bin/classes/./com/google/android/gms/R$string.class...
processing bin/classes/./com/google/android/gms/R$style.class...
processing bin/classes/./com/google/android/gms/R$styleable.class...
processing bin/classes/./com/google/android/gms/R$xml.class...
processing bin/classes/./com/google/android/gms/R.class...
processing bin/classes/./com/test/asdf/Manifest$permission.class...
processing bin/classes/./com/test/asdf/Manifest.class...
processing bin/classes/./com/test/asdf/R$attr.class...
processing bin/classes/./com/test/asdf/R$bool.class...
processing bin/classes/./com/test/asdf/R$color.class...
processing bin/classes/./com/test/asdf/R$dimen.class...
processing bin/classes/./com/test/asdf/R$drawable.class...
processing bin/classes/./com/test/asdf/R$id.class...
processing bin/classes/./com/test/asdf/R$integer.class...
processing bin/classes/./com/test/asdf/R$layout.class...
processing bin/classes/./com/test/asdf/R$raw.class...
processing bin/classes/./com/test/asdf/R$string.class...
processing bin/classes/./com/test/asdf/R$style.class...
processing bin/classes/./com/test/asdf/R$styleable.class...
processing bin/classes/./com/test/asdf/R$xml.class...
processing bin/classes/./com/test/asdf/R.class...
processing archive plugins/./an_billing.jar...
ignored resource META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
processing com/android/vending/billing/IInAppBillingService$Stub$Proxy.class...
processing com/android/vending/billing/IInAppBillingService$Stub.class...
processing com/android/vending/billing/IInAppBillingService.class...
processing com/androidnative/billing/core/AN_BillingProxyActivity$1.class...
processing com/androidnative/billing/core/AN_BillingProxyActivity.class...
processing com/androidnative/billing/core/BillingHelper$1.class...
processing com/androidnative/billing/core/BillingHelper$2$1.class...
processing com/androidnative/billing/core/BillingHelper$2.class...
processing com/androidnative/billing/core/BillingHelper$3$1.class...
processing com/androidnative/billing/core/BillingHelper$3$2.class...
processing com/androidnative/billing/core/BillingHelper$3.class...
processing com/androidnative/billing/core/BillingHelper.class...
processing com/androidnative/billing/core/BillingManager$1.class...
processing com/androidnative/billing/core/BillingManager$2.class...
processing com/androidnative/billing/core/BillingManager$3.class...
processing com/androidnative/billing/core/BillingManager.class...
processing com/androidnative/billing/core/listeners/AN_PurchaseFinishedListener.class...
processing com/androidnative/billing/core/listeners/AN_QueryInventoryFinishedListener.class...
processing com/androidnative/billing/interfaces/OnBillingPurchaseFinishedListener.class...
processing com/androidnative/billing/interfaces/OnBillingSetupFinishedListener.class...
processing com/androidnative/billing/interfaces/OnConsumeFinishedListener.class...
processing com/androidnative/billing/interfaces/OnConsumeMultiFinishedListener.class...
processing com/androidnative/billing/interfaces/QueryInventoryFinishedListener.class...
processing com/androidnative/billing/models/BillingException.class...
processing com/androidnative/billing/models/BillingResult.class...
processing com/androidnative/billing/models/Inventory.class...
processing com/androidnative/billing/models/Purchase.class...
processing com/androidnative/billing/models/Security.class...
processing com/androidnative/billing/models/SkuDetails.class...
processing com/androidnative/billing/util/Base64.class...
processing com/androidnative/billing/util/Base64DecoderException.class...
processing archive plugins/./an_googleplay.jar...
ignored resource META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
processing com/androidnative/an_googleplay/BuildConfig.class...
processing com/androidnative/an_googleplay/R$attr.class...
processing com/androidnative/an_googleplay/R$drawable.class...
processing com/androidnative/an_googleplay/R$id.class...
processing com/androidnative/an_googleplay/R$layout.class...
processing com/androidnative/an_googleplay/R$string.class...
processing com/androidnative/an_googleplay/R$style.class...
processing com/androidnative/an_googleplay/R.class...
processing com/androidnative/gcm/ANCloudMessageService$1.class...
processing com/androidnative/gcm/ANCloudMessageService$2.class...
processing com/androidnative/gcm/ANCloudMessageService.class...
processing com/androidnative/gcm/GcmBroadcastReceiver.class...
processing com/androidnative/gcm/GcmIntentService.class...
processing com/androidnative/gms/ad/ANMobileAd.class...
processing com/androidnative/gms/ad/AdInAppListner.class...
processing com/androidnative/gms/ad/BannerAdListner.class...
processing com/androidnative/gms/ad/GADBanner.class...
processing com/androidnative/gms/ad/InterstitialAdListner.class...
processing com/androidnative/gms/analytics/AN_AnalyticsProxy.class...
processing com/androidnative/gms/analytics/V4GoogleAnalytics.class...
processing com/androidnative/gms/core/GameClientBridge.class...
processing com/androidnative/gms/core/GameClientManager$1.class...
processing com/androidnative/gms/core/GameClientManager$2.class...
processing com/androidnative/gms/core/GameClientManager$3.class...
processing com/androidnative/gms/core/GameClientManager$4.class...
processing com/androidnative/gms/core/GameClientManager$5.class...
processing com/androidnative/gms/core/GameClientManager.class...
processing com/androidnative/gms/core/GameInvitationManager.class...
processing com/androidnative/gms/core/GooglePlaySupportActivity$1.class...
processing com/androidnative/gms/core/GooglePlaySupportActivity.class...
processing com/androidnative/gms/core/NewGameHelper.class...
processing com/androidnative/gms/listeners/appstate/StateDeleteListener.class...
processing com/androidnative/gms/listeners/appstate/StateUpdateListener.class...
processing com/androidnative/gms/listeners/appstate/StatesLoadedListener.class...
processing com/androidnative/gms/listeners/games/AchievementsLoadListner.class...
processing com/androidnative/gms/listeners/games/AchievementsUpdateListner.class...
processing com/androidnative/gms/listeners/games/LeaderBoardScoreLoaded.class...
processing com/androidnative/gms/listeners/games/LeaderBoardsLoadedListener.class...
processing com/androidnative/gms/listeners/games/PlayerResultListner.class...
processing com/androidnative/gms/listeners/games/PlayerScoreUpdateListner.class...
processing com/androidnative/gms/listeners/games/ScoreSubmitedListner.class...
processing com/androidnative/gms/listeners/network/AN_OnInvitationReceivedListener.class...
processing com/androidnative/gms/listeners/network/AN_RealTimeMessageReceivedListener.class...
processing com/androidnative/gms/listeners/network/AN_RoomStatusUpdateListener.class...
processing com/androidnative/gms/listeners/network/AN_RoomUpdateListener.class...
processing com/androidnative/gms/listeners/quests/AN_AcceptQuestResultListner.class...
processing com/androidnative/gms/listeners/quests/AN_ClaimMilestoneResult.class...
processing com/androidnative/gms/listeners/quests/AN_EventsLoadListner.class...
processing com/androidnative/gms/listeners/quests/AN_LoadQuestsResult.class...
processing com/androidnative/gms/listeners/quests/AN_QuestUpdateListener.class...
processing com/androidnative/gms/listeners/requests/AN_LoadRequestsResultListner.class...
processing com/androidnative/gms/listeners/requests/AN_UpdateRequestsResultListner.class...
processing com/androidnative/gms/listeners/savedgames/DeleteSnapShotListner.class...
processing com/androidnative/gms/listeners/savedgames/DeleteSpapShotResultListner.class...
processing com/androidnative/gms/listeners/savedgames/LoadSnapshotsResultListner.class...
processing com/androidnative/gms/listeners/savedgames/OpenSnapshotListner.class...
processing com/androidnative/gms/listeners/savedgames/SnapshotCreateListner.class...
processing com/androidnative/gms/listeners/savedgames/SnapshotMetadataChangeListner.class...
processing com/androidnative/<message truncated>
```

Answer (score 3):

It looks like one of the plugins is saving the value of `com.google.android.gms.version` in the AndroidManifest.xml itself, and the other uses a [string resource](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html); I suppose that there's a file `integer.xml` somewhere in the source, and when you find it, there would be a value of `google_play_services_version` hidden inside. The `com.google.android.gms.version` itself seems to be a required version of Google Play Services; it's reasonable that it would be backward compatible, so I would just pick the largest number out of those two. Check [this](http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/setup.html) for details (switch to "Something else" to see the configuration details).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I followed the second link provided and I got past the `unable to merge manifests error`. Unfortunately, after fixing that, I am presented with a new error `Unable to convert classes into dex format`. I edited my post to include this new error message I am receiving in the console. By any chance, do you know what's going on and how to fix it?

Comment: No, unfortunately I don't know how to help with that. If I would be in that situation, I would try launching the same command that Unity launches in the command line and dig into it's output to pinpoint that exact file where it happens. Also, this error seems like it should be another question :)

Answer (score 2):

Hi Guys I had an exact similar problem and the Unity thread I mean this [link](https://answers.unity.com/questions/1325379/android-unable-to-merge-android-manifest-error-2.html) and this [one](https://forum.unity.com/threads/unable-to-merge-android-manifests.449825/) said that update and change the API level and follow up the crap, I also highly recommend to update the android SKD and set JAVA_HOME and ANDROID_HOME in your system variables like me in the following picture

[image]

and set path variables for adb.exe and java.exe in your system like this one

[image]

BUT what I tried and fixed my problem was that I changed the build system to new **Gradle**! and that was it.

[image]

Cheers =)

Answer (score 0):

For your second question:

This is most likely a result of having duplicate .jar files in your project.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31996201/3830479) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

its very much straightforward, you need to navigate to location: \Assets\Plugins\Android. Locate all AndroidManifest.xml files and update the sdk version as per the given error.

Answer (score 0):

1 - (If you are VR developer)download "tools_r25.2.3-windows.zip" from "https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html" then replace it with tools folder in your Android Studio folder!!!

2 - You should work with unity version 5.5.0! the version 5.6.x doesn't work really good!!

3 - the best version for gvr-unity-sdk(If you are VR developer) is 1.0.3! The greater doesn't work good!!!

4 - (If you are VR developer)Right click on "My Computer" and select "Properties"/Go to "Advanced System setting"/Click "Environment Variables"/In "system variables" look for "Path" click on it then click "Edit" . In "variable value" add a semicolon sign(;) to the end of default path, then add the path of where u install Android Studio/platform-tools folder for example my path is "G:\AndroidSDK\platform-tools".......

I hope your problem will be solved!!!