# Unity 5.1.1 android "merged manifest" or "classes into dex format" error

Tags: facebook-unity-sdk

I tried this versions on my unity 5.1.1 (6.2.2, 7.0.1, 7.0.2) and I get errors in all when I build that in android.

Any idea?

In the 'stable version 6.2.2 I get "unable to convert files into dex format"

errors:

1.
CommandInvokationFailure: Unable to convert classes into dex format. See the Console for details.

> C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_17\bin\java.exe -Xmx2048M -Dcom.android.sdkmanager.toolsdir="C:/Program Files (x86)/Android/android-sdk\tools" -Dfile.encoding=UTF8 -jar "C:/Program Files/Unity/Editor/Data/BuildTargetTools/AndroidPlayer\sdktools.jar" -
>   stderr[
>   UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added: Landroid/support/v4/util/TimeUtils;
>   ets..

2.
Error building Player: CommandInvokationFailure: Unable to convert classes into dex format. See the Console for details.

> C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_17\bin\java.exe -Xmx2048M -Dcom.android.sdkmanager.toolsdir="C:/Program Files (x86)/Android/android-sdk\tools" -Dfile.encoding=UTF8 -jar "C:/Program Files/Unity/Editor/Data/BuildTargetTools/AndroidPlayer\sdktools.jar" -
>   stderr[
>   UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added: Landroid/support/v4/util/TimeUtils;
>       at com.android.dx.dex.file.ClassDefsSection.add(ClassDefsSection.java:122)
>       at com.android.dx.dex.file.DexFile.add(DexFile.java:161)
>       at

ets..

In the 7.0.2 I get **"can't merge manifest files"**

Answer (score 0):

This is most likely a result of having duplicate .jar files in your project. Try searching where your TimeUtils is, and making sure there are no similar .jar files in your Assets/Plugins/Android folder -- make sure to check deeper into folders within the Android folder. Note that it might not be an exact duplicate title (a different version number might also cause the problem).

I had this same issue with the push notifications plugin on my app (I had 2 so I removed one).